# What is an "overflow winger"?

Tags: football, terminology

Can somebody explain to me what an "overflow winger" is?

I read today NKoudou is going on loan to Burnley. Mauricio Pochettino is said to prefer "winger-leaders" like Lamela and Eriksen to "overflow wingers".

The only reference to this term I have found online is when discussion Thierry Henry's previous position at Monaco when he played on the wing.

I guess "overflow-winger" describes a traditional winger, a role taken over by the wing-back in a lot of modern teams (like Tottenham). But I wonder if somebody out there knows for sure.

[NKoudou to go on loan to Burnley](https://cartilagefreecaptain.sbnation.com/2018/1/9/16866578/tottenham-hotspur-transfer-news-rumors-gk-nkoudou-loan-burnley-end-of-season)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term originates from French ("ailier de débordement") and got probably translated badly in the process.

If my French isn't too rusty you're right and it's just a term for a traditional Winger who's main purpose is to overrun and escape the defenders (not "overflow" them). (See [this](https://www.eurosport.fr/football/le-football-a-tourne-la-page-des-ailiers-de-debordement-et-il-ne-sen-porte-pas-plus-mal_sto4659534/story.shtml) article)